# How to build a disk status chart?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a html like this for displaying disk status on my page which is in React. I was hoping to find a reusable component like this. What is this type of chart called so that I could look for any available implementations?  Would this be part of some charting  library?

[image]

Where do I start if I were to build this from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically talking about a few progress bars put together... Here is how to make a progress bar in React:

Main Component:

```
class ProgressBarExample extends React.Component {
  state = { percentage: 0 };

  nextStep = () => {
    if (this.state.percentage === 100) return;
    this.setState({ percentage: this.state.percentage + 20 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2> A React Progress Bar </h2>
        <ProgressBar percentage={this.state.percentage} />

        <div style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
          <button onClick={this.nextStep}>Next Step</button>
        </div>

        <div
          style={{ marginTop: '10px', color: 'blue', marginBottom: '15px' }}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ percentage: 0 })}
        >
          Reset
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is your progress bar component:

```
const ProgressBar = props => {
  return (
    <div className="progress-bar">
      <Filler percentage={props.percentage} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And here is your filler:

```
const Filler = props => {
  return <div className="filler" style={{ width: `${props.percentage}%` }} />;
};
```

**Here is live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wk628wy5yk**

Answer (score 4):

You can use HTML5 `<progress>` element to achieve this. 
More information on progress element [Link](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/)